# What font is being used in the latex document

Tags: fonts

[image]

What font is being used here? The text resembles "Computer Modern" (though the texture is dark) but the italic text doesn't resemble Computer Modern. Can anyone help me out with the packages for using these fonts?

Comment: Are there any reasons that make you believe this was typeset with TeX? My impression is that the page was typeset with a Monotype machine, which explains why the font resembles CM.

Comment: @egreg Fair enough, I agree on what you say. By the way, can these fonts be atleast reproduced in TeX?

Comment: If you have a .pdf of the document, your .pdf viewer usually can give you the list of fonts in use via the` Document properties` menu.

Comment: For information, the article has been published by the American Mathematical Monthly in 1963 https://www.jstor.org/stable/2311859